# Security optimal file permissions django+apache+mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, security, permissions

I'm just about getting started on deploying my first live Django website, and I'm wondering how to set the Ubuntu server file permissions in the optimal way for security, whilst still granting the permissions required.

Firstly a question of directories: I'm currently storing the site in `~/www/mysite.com/{Django apps}`, but have often seen people using `/var/www/...` or `/srv/www`; is there any reason picking one of these directories is better than the other? or any reason why keeping the site in my home dir is a bad idea?

Secondly, the permissions of the dir and files themselves. I'm serving using apache with `mod_wsgi`, and have the file `WSGIScriptAlias / ~/www/mysite.com/mainapp/wsgi.py` file. Apache runs as `www-data` user. For optimal security who should own the `wsgi.py` file, and what permissions should I grant it and its containing dir?

Similarly, for the `www`, `www/mysite.com`, and `www/mysite.com/someapp` directories? What are the minimal permissions that are needed for the dirs and files?

Currently I am using `755` and `644` for dir and files respecitvely, which works well enough which allows the site to function, but I wonder if it is optimal/too liberal. My Ubuntu user is the owner of most files, and `www-data` owns the `sqlite` dbs.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to serving the application from your home directory, this is primarily preference based. However, deployment decisions may be made depending on the situation. For example, if you have multiple users making use of this server to host their website, then you would likely have the files served from their home directories. From a system administrator's perspective that is deploying the applications; you may want them all accessible from /var/www... so they are easier to locate.

The permissions you set for serving the files seem fine, however they may need to run as different users... depending on the number of people using this machine. For example, lets say you have one other application running on the server and that both applications run as www-data. If the www-data user has read permissions of Django's config file, then the other user could deploy a script that can read your database credentials.